# Would a seat post mounted back rack act like a rear fender?

Tags: accessories

Specifically I want to know if the right one would stop the rider's back from getting splattered with rain. That way it does double duty as a fender and a rack.I want a light duty back rack for day to day cargo. If I am getting bulky groceries or doing the laundry I can always use a backpack.
I like the minimalist lines of some of the ones I have seen. They suit my bike.

Comment: Not very good fender as it is too narrow

Comment: With personal experience, I found even a reasonably long back rack wasn't long enough to keep my back from being splattered by muddy water during the rain. I added a homemade plastic extension to my rack to catch the farthest drops, which did the job but was pretty ugly.

Comment: @kgutwin as ugly as the one I posted in my answer?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it depends on the length of the rack you're going to attach.

It's all about the physics - the water droplets, when they detach from the tyre they move perpendicular to the perimeter of the wheel. If the rack is long enough, the droplets that might reach your back are hitting the rack (acting as a mudguard).

The ideal situation would be when the rack reaches to the furthest rear point of the wheel. Then only the droplets travelling vertically are not covered by the rack.

However when the rack gets shorter, the more droplets travel to the front, thus direction of your back.

Short story long - have a look at the picture:

- black is the bicycle (obvious)
- red is the rack
- blue is the  most front-travelling droplet that might hit your back

[image: bicycle with rack as a mudguard]
I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Great answer.  Another thing to consider is that water can actually get flung forward and make the back of your legs and feet wet so it’s important to have some coverage behind your seat post.

Comment: @RoboKaren has a point here. One solution would be to attach another mudguard on the seat tube, which will only partly be a solution, or ride wearing shorts to minimise the amount of clothing affected by water. The most elegant yet effective solution would be to use considerably wide mudguard reaching from chain stays up to seat stays.

Comment: Not just legs and feet (@RoboKaren) but the chainrings and front derailleur, contributing to wear if the water is gritty (i.e. always)

Comment: In practice you need longer fender, because the droplets don't fly straight but roughly in a parabolical arc (with some interference from air)

Comment: It's true, @ojs, gravity contributes to that. But in fact, at the moment that the parabolic distortion might affect the droplet hitting the back of the rider, they are already further ahead escaping this droplet.

Comment: Your drawings show the straight line trajectory in the bike's coordinate system. If you want to think that the rider is also further ahead when the droplet hits, you'll need to draw the trajectories in stationary coordinates.

Comment: @ojs and then you get into the effect of the headwind on the drops (i.e. even in a stationary reference frame their path is curved; you can observe this by watching a bike ride past you if the drops catch the light, such as from a seatpost-mounted rear light)

Comment: @ChrisH yes, and then there's a vortex behind the rider. It gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Any rack that has a plate on top, however it's mounted, can be a *partial* mudguard. I've found a tail made from the end of a cheap plastic mudguard improves the coverage a lot. On one of my bikes I've taken this a step further with mudguard (in two pieces) from behind the bottom bracket, past the brakes and up to the rack in addition to the tail. It's not pretty, but this is a bike that's meant to look even older and cheaper than it is.

On other bikes I've managed to get a full mudguard underneath.

The further a mudguard is from the tyre, the wider it needs to be to do any good. This is a further limitation.

Some from my fleet (all bikes have been ridden in mud recently):

[image: 3 rear racks]

(click for bigger pictures)

- Top: a Topeak *Beam Rack DX* stops a little mud, but not much (as can be seen from the spatter on top of the rack).  Just after taking this I fitted a Crudcatcher mudguard.
- Middle: a Topeak *Super Tourist DX* is much better (partly because it fits closer to the tyre) but I've added plastic.
- Bottom: A Tortec *Velocity Hybrid* does nothing (no plate) -- note the full mudguard underneath.

The mods to the middle one consist of a tail, which makes a big difference:

[image: mudguard tail]

and some coverage at the front for the drivetrain and my legs:

[image: front of rear mudguard]

Comment: Concur - I've lined the underside of a parcel rack, to make it an effective half-mudguard.  I extended the rack backward by lengthening the mounts and the rails though, and this did nothing for the frontmost quarter of the wheel.

Comment: That sounds about right if the rack itself doesn't do everything asked of it.